# discord.py How to make a command that does different things in different channels

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a game discord bot that has different channels as different "areas," but I want the same command to do different things depending on what channel it was used in.

This is what I have right now:

```
@client.command()
async def fish(ctx):
  author = ctx.message.author
  channel = ctx.message.channel
  if channel == 'pallet-town' or channel == 'viridian-city' or channel == 'route-4':
    await ctx.send(f"{author.mention}, do you want to use your old, good, or super rod?")
  else:
    await ctx.send('No water here!')
```

However, this returns "No water here!" even if I am in one of the aforementioned channels. Does anyone know why this is happening? Do I need to use the channel ID instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`channel` is a `discord.TextChannel` instance and you're comparing it to a string, that's never `True`, simply cast `channel` to a string:

```py
async def fish(ctx):
    author = ctx.message.author
    channel = ctx.message.channel
    if str(channel) == 'pallet-town' or str(channel) == 'viridian-city' or str(channel) == 'route-4':
        await ctx.send(f"{author.mention}, do you want to use your old, good, or super rod?")
    else:
        await ctx.send('No water here!')
```

PS: You can really shorten the code with:

```py
if str(channel) in ["pallet-town", "viridian-city", "route-4"]:
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you! This solution makes it much easier to add more areas in the future.

Answer (score 1):

In the way you currently have it configured, you're checking if a `Channel` object is equal to a string `'pallet-town'` etc. You need to check if the `.name` attribute of that channel is equal to your string instead.

You should be able to just replace the line:

```
channel = ctx.message.channel
```

with:

```
channel = ctx.message.channel.name
```